# Simulation of custom probability distribution in Matlab

Tags: probability-distributions, matlab

I'm trying to simulate the following distribution:

```
 a   |  0   |  1   |  7   |  11  |  13 
-----------------------------------------
p(a) | 0.34 | 0.02 | 0.24 | 0.29 | 0.11
```

I already simulated a similar problem: four type of balls with chances of 0.3, 0.1, 0.4 and 0.2. I created a vector `F = [0 0.3 0.4 0.8 1]` and used repmat to grow it by 1000 rows. Then I compared it with a columnvector of 1000 random numbers grown with 5 columns using the same `repmat` approach. I compared those two, calculated the sumvector of the matrix, and calculated the difference to get the frequences (e.g. `[301 117 386 196]`).

But with the current distribution I don't know how to create the initial matrix `F` and whether I can use the same approach I used before at all.

I need the answer to be "vectorised", so no (`for`, `while` or `if`) loops.

[This question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067014/simulation-of-custom-distribution-in-matlab)

Comment: I suggest you post this question on Stackoverflow as well, and link the posts to each other. You'll get very elaborate MATLAB answers very quickly.

Comment: @Lisa I was just about to do that. Thanks for the tip tho ;)

Comment: Ok sorry I was a bit quick then :) Anyway, I'm interested in the answer you'll get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't this be what you're looking for?

```
y = randsample([0 1 7 11 13],100,true,[0.34 0.02 0.24 0.29 0.11])
```

For larger sample sizes, just change `100` to whatever you want.

Comment: What is this magic? Clearly I need to look more into these kind of magic MatLab functions.

Comment: @Joren It's almost as if the developers tried to make matlab easy to use... :-)